# How to set attributes for form field rendered by two inputs in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.4

I have date field in symfony2 which is rendered by two inputs:

```
   $builder

            ->add('timeStart','datetime',array(
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'time_widget' => 'single_text',
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'data' => new \DateTime('now')
            ))
```

how to set attributes for each input? When I add `attr=>array('some_attr'=>'some_value')` it is added to the div in which those inputs are, not to each input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set each's input attribute when rendering inside the twig template. Something like this would do:

```
{{ form_widget(form.timeStart, { attributes1 } ) }}
```

And

```
{{ form_widget(form.timeStart, { attributes2 } ) }}
```

Take a look at the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables).